# Using ngx-highlightjs npm package, getting error 'Can't bind to 'highlight' since it isn't a known property of 'code'.'

Tags: angular

I have searched many hours, tried many things but cannot clear this error. My webstorm IDE recognizes the [highlight] attribute, but the compiler does not. All of the examples on NPM use standalone components. I'm using @NgModule. Shouldn't that work too?

UPDATE 10/13/2023: I've since tried with standalone project with same result. I am using Nx monorepo. The build shows the feature is being lazy loaded. I suspect that is the root of the problem and I need to figure out how to not use lazy loading.

Below are relevant code snippets.

What am I missing?

Angular 15, Nx Mono Repo, Shared library.

```
Error: libs/shared/src/lib/dumb/code-from-url/code-from-url.component.html:22:15 -

error NG8002: Can't bind to 'highlight' since it isn't a known property of 'code'.

22         <code [highlight]="content"></code>
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/elements": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "15.2.0",
        "ngx-highlightjs": "^10.0.0",
    },
```

```
import {
    HighlightAutoResult,
    HighlightLoader,
    HighlightModule,
    HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
    HighlightOptions,
} from 'ngx-highlightjs';

...

@NgModule({

...

    providers: [

        {
            provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: <HighlightOptions>{
                lineNumbers: false,
                coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
                languages: {
                    java: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/java'),
                    xml: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml'),
                    json: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/json'),
                },
            },
        },

    ]
})
export class SharedModule {

}
```